# cmake Cannot link to custom boost when ubuntu boost package is installed

Tags: ubuntu, boost, cmake

Building UHD (http://ettus-apps.sourcerepo.com/redmine/ettus/projects/uhd/wiki)
download link https://github.com/EttusResearch/UHD-Mirror/zipball/release_003_004_003
I want to choose the Boost version that I'm using

Using Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit
I've built a custom Boost with -fPIC. I use static link
I edit host/CMakeLists.txt file and added

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT "/home/bastien/verisat/lib_boost_1_49_0_with_test_po_fPIC")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/home/bastien/verisat/lib_boost_1_49_0_with_test_po_fPIC/include")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/home/bastien/verisat/lib_boost_1_49_0_with_test_po_fPIC/lib")
```

before these 3 lines that were already in the file

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.49 COMPONENTS ${BOOST_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Never the less it always link to boost in /usr/lib rather than the one specified
When I remove the boost ubuntu package

```
sudo apt-get remove libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then it works and point to the boost version specified

I'd like to be able to do so without having to uninstall the default boost ?
Default is 1.46 and mine 1.49, but setting minimum version did not help

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS` variable:

```
#   Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS        Set to TRUE to suppress searching in system
#                                paths (or other locations outside of BOOST_ROOT
#                                or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR).  Useful when specifying
#                                BOOST_ROOT. Defaults to OFF.
#                                  [Since CMake 2.8.3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the correct version somewhere and use the environment variable `BOOST_ROOT` to specify it.  CMake will try that before the normal system paths.

Comment: I agree. I'm also using a custom boost with cmake over the default boost, and setting `SET(BOOST_ROOT /dev/cpp/gcc47/boost)` prior to `FIND_PACKAGE(Boost...` works perfectly.

Comment: I have done that... as shown in the question. But it did not work until I uninstalled the default ubuntu boost (as sated in the question...)

Comment: @user611191 That is very strange.  Perhaps because its the same version it prefers the base installed one?  I can't say that I've come across that before.